# Is it possible to get other device information from just a UDID?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ipod, udid

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any methods for retrieving device information from just a device's UDID (iOS). For example, if a client gives you a device UDID, is it at all possible to find out the device model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The UDID is an SHA1 hash of a few components, and for all intents and purpose, impossible to reverse.

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/UDID

You can get the information you need from [UIDevice currentDevice]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Apple holds such information of any iOS device ever sold. They probably even know the original owner and the current OS version installed on the device since the don't allow installing without their on-line approval.

If you are an admin of an [Apple Development Program](https://developer.apple.com) (or have an individual developer account), you can register the UDID for development and get some information for the given UDID (such as platform, device class and model).

You can even [do it programatically](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship)!

- NOTE 1: Apple might be monitoring such activity. IANAL and I'm not aware of the legal consequences of getting information of devices you don't own.
- NOTE 2: Development Program accounts are limited in the number of devices they can register.

Use wisely...